# Package.json - set main directory

Tags: node.js, package.json

I'm building a library with no default export, but a whole set of sub-exports. It's documentation for a set of APIs, so each API is exported from its own sub-directory. There is no central API info that should be exported from, say, `dist/index.js`, but instead, there's `dist/api-one/index.js`, `dist/api-two/index.js`, etc.

Currently, I'm importing like so: `import { SomeFeatureOfApiOne } from 'my-package/dist/api-one`

But it'd be nice to be able to get rid of the `dist` in the import path, since everything will have it. I know the `files` parameter just determines which directories are included in the export, so that doesn't work, and it appears that `main` is for the actual module file, not a directory.

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of maybe a `postinstall` script that moves the sub-directories from `/dist` to root, but that feels super hacky to me, so I was hoping there was a neater way.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
"exports": {
    "./*": "./dist/*.js"
},
```

to your `package.json`
You can read more about `"exports"` here - https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports